# How to understand the Bilinear mapping with an example

Tags: pairings, group-theory

An efficient bilinear map is given by  $ e $: $G_{1}$ × $G_{1}$ → $G_{T} $.

How can i prove this equation with the help of an example.

Comment: You don't need to prove. You need to evaluate its correctness, i guess

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice within 5 hours? And then you are even more unclear than in [How to Mathematically Prove the Bilinear Pairing Properties](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12928/how-to-mathematically-prove-the-bilinear-pairing-properties)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question.